# why does oh-my-zsh terminal macos missing symbols?

Tags: macos, terminal, fonts, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have problem with ohmyzsh. I've installed it on catalina 10.15.7 from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luSonG4-Xis.
on tutorial after install, themes works out of the box. In my case I have missing symbols and symbol '?' for them. Any ideas what could go wrong?
I've tried install powerline fonts with no luck.

[missing symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAggN.png)

Comment: You did not write what font you are using in your terminal. BTW, this question should be posted at [superuser](https://superuser.com/). Correctly displaying certain fonts is not related to zsh.

Answer (score 8):

Go into **Terminal->Preferences->Profiles->Text**

Under **Font** click **Change**

Choose **Meslo LG S DZ Regular for Powerline**